# Laravel - Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, static

I have recently started using laravel for work and I boumped into many issues I cannot stil solve.
I have looked over many many topics and already anwered questions but none of those have helped me with my issue
So, I get this error trying to do 'php artisan serve'
"Non-static method Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::for() should not be called statically"

So I went up looking at the code, this is the RateLimiter.php code that gives me the error

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
   {
       RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
           return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
       });
   }
```

the error is at the 2nd line of this code, in the RateLimiter:: etc

I get those errors in the CMD

app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:59
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Non-static method Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::for() should not be called statically", "myPathToTheProject/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php", [])

app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:38
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::configureRateLimiting()

the function is called like this
`$this->configureRateLimiting();`

hoping you can help me, I will give more infos if are needed

Comment: What if use `for` like this `$rateLimiter = new RateLimiter();` and after `$rateLimiter->for()...` ?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but looking at the docs for [`RateLimiter`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#rate-limiting) it looks like it can be used as a facade. But this makes me think the OP is just importing it wrong since the error says a different namespace.

Comment: looking at the project composition, I see that there is ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter``` and maybe this is the thing I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. You need to import the facade, and when you auto-import, it tends to get the wrong package.
Look at the imports. If you find:

```
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;
```

You should replace with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
```

Worked for me!